# What the difference between glProgramUniform() and glUniform()?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have read the specification from khronos, I know that glProgramUniform*() uploads data to the specified program object and that glUniform*() uploads data to the currently bound program object. But I want to know if there are any other different between those two like performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only difference guaranteed by the spec is the one you already mentioned: There is no need to bind the shader before using the `glProgramUniform*` command family.

If there are any performance differences, then they are vendor/driver/version specific.

Note, that `glUniform*` is available since 2.0 while `glProgramUniform` was introduced in 4.1.

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, “less GL instructions” is a good thing. That's because, in modern hardware, the bottle neck is in the communication between CPU and GPU.

So avoiding the bind here is the key difference.

The new `glProgramUniform()` is part of the [Direct State Access (DSA)](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Direct_State_Access).
A model closer to how hardware works today and intended to approach to the ideal zero driver overhead.